# Export of GraphicsRow to PDF is ugly

Tags: plotting, graphics, export, format

I have a problem with exporting `GraphicsRow[{Plot, Plot, Plot,...}]` object to pdf.

The line is like

```
GraphicsRow[
    {pFit11, pFit12, pFit13, pFit14, pFit15}
  , PlotLabel -> "-2≤lγ≤2, w=5.9, θ=0.07"
  , Spacings -> 10
  , ImageSize -> Full
  , PlotRange -> All
]
```

what I see in the output is

[image]

But what appears in the pdf after I export it as

```
Export["...\Plot.pdf", #];
```

is this ugly thing:

[image]

How can I fix it taking into consideration that I am restricted with converting only in PDF?

Thanks!

Comment: what version are you using?

Comment: MMA10 (student edition) on Mac

Comment: You might want to consider posting a minimal working example so that people can copy and paste it into MMA and see exactly what's the problem. In such a case you are more likely to draw attention to your question and receive answers.

Comment: @corey979 It is not related to the particular form of my functions. you can put anything in there... It is related to the data formatting during the export, as far as I get it...

Comment: With the plots I just made up, the exported plot is reasonable, so I'm tempted to say I can't reproduce your issue. However, note that in the [docs of `ImageSize`, under Details](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageSize.html?q=ImageSize) it's writen that "For an **object that appears directly in a notebook** cell, `ImageSize->Full` corresponds to the **full width of the content area for the cell**" (highlights are mine). So, this option is for displaying in a notebook, not for export. You'd need to rescale the images correctly first in the notebook.